# Pivoting a text file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Given a data file, I want to transpose certain columns to rows using awk.

The input data file has one column per month, like this:

```
FirstName|LastName|Jan|Feb|Mar
First_1|Last_1|1|10|100
First_2|Last_2|2|20|200
First_3|Last_3|3|30|300
```

I want to keep the first two columns, and transpose the months to rows. My expected output would be:

```
First_1|Last_1|Jan|1
First_1|Last_1|Feb|10
First_1|Last_1|Mar|100
First_2|Last_2|Jan|2
First_2|Last_2|Feb|20
First_2|Last_2|Mar|200
First_3|Last_3|Jan|3
First_3|Last_3|Feb|30
First_3|Last_3|Mar|300
```

I tried

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1 {{OFS="|"} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$2,$i}}}' input_file
```

which gives me almost the desired output:

```
First_1|Last_1|1
First_1|Last_1|10
First_1|Last_1|100
First_2|Last_2|2
First_2|Last_2|20
First_2|Last_2|200
First_3|Last_3|3
First_3|Last_3|30
First_3|Last_3|300
```

But I am unable to add the month column. I tried this:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>1 {{OFS="|"} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$2,NR==1 {print $i}},$i}}}' input_file
```

but I get a syntax error.

Comment: On SO we do encourage people to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem. Please do add the same and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR>0 {{OFS="|"} {if (NR==1) {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {x[i-3]=$i;}} else {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {print $1,$2,x[i-3],$i }}}}' input_file
```

What above script does is when it is parsing the first row `NR==1`, it copies the months into an array `x` using the `for` loop (`for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {x[i-3]=$i;}`). Later that array is used by loop variable `i` as index to obtain the correct month value (`x[i-3]`).

Two changes were made to your script:

1) Added the following part to extract the month names and store it into an array.

```
if (NR==1) {for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {x[i-3]=$i;}
```

2) Then the array is added to the print statement.

```
print $1,$2,x[i-3],$i
```

Result:

```
First_1|Last_1|Jan|1
First_1|Last_1|Feb|10
First_1|Last_1|Mar|100
First_2|Last_2|Jan|2
First_2|Last_2|Feb|20
First_2|Last_2|Mar|200
First_3|Last_3|Jan|3
First_3|Last_3|Feb|30
First_3|Last_3|Mar|300
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
       NR==1 { print "FirstName|LastName|Month|Value"
               for (n = 3; n <= NF; n++) months[n] = $n
               next }
       { for (n = 3; n <= NF; n++) print $1, $2, months[n], $n }' input.txt
FirstName|LastName|Month|Value
First_1|Last_1|Jan|1
First_1|Last_1|Feb|2
First_1|Last_1|Mar|3
First_2|Last_2|Jan|2
First_2|Last_2|Feb|4
First_2|Last_2|Mar|6
First_3|Last_3|Jan|3
First_3|Last_3|Feb|6
First_3|Last_3|Mar|9
```